# Get PostgreSQL statistics for all tables?

Tags: postgresql, statistics

I have seen that PostgreSQL have several [statistics](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/monitoring-stats.html) depending on every table's OID (like the number of inserts, and so) [1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/monitoring-stats.html).
What I am looking for is some kind of `SELECT` query or something that would sum up everything for every table.
It would be something like:

`SELECT SUM(pg_stat_get_db_tuples_returned(SELECT oid FROM pg_class));`
Or something like that. I would apreciate any help in here.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this:

```
SELECT SUM(pg_stat_get_db_tuples_returned(oid))
from pg_class;
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, with your choice of stats function, aggregates the stats function on all tables except temporary and system catalog tables:

```
SELECT
  sum(pg_stat_get_db_tuples_returned(c.oid))
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
  INNER JOIN pg_namespace n ON (c.relnamespace = n.oid)
WHERE NOT (n.nspname LIKE ANY(ARRAY['pg_temp%','pg_catalog','information_schema']));
```

Note that `pg_toast` schemas *are* included in this, as I presume you want your stats to include any TOAST side-tables. If you don't, add `pg_toast%` to the exclusions.

Edit: I was using the construct:

```
(quote_ident(n.nspname)||'.'||quote_ident(c.relname))::regclass
```

to get the table oid, but that's just silly when it's right there in `pg_class`; it's ridiculously roundabout as shown by a_horse_with_no_name.